# Remove rows from matrix where ID = NA

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix like:

```
ID | Row2 | Row3 | ...

1  |  A   |  B   | ...

1  |  A   |  NA  | ...

1  |  NA  |  B   | ...

NA |  A   |  B   | ...

NA |  A   |  B   | ...
```

I need to remove all rows where ID = NA. Doesn't matter if Row2,Row3,etc. have NAs as values. How could i do that?

I have these code sample to get the NAs of the columns ID:

```
!is.na(mMasterdata[,"ID"])
```

How could I apply this to the matrix?

Comment: `mat[!is.na(mat[, "ID"]), ]`

Comment: thanks that solved it! And sry didn't find the duplicated question with google :/

Comment: no problem, sometimes its difficult to find one. Glad it helped. :)